# GEdit: spell check multiple languages -- Is there a way?

Tags: gedit, text-editor, spell-checking

I have migrated to Linux (Ubuntu) from Windows, where I used Notepad++ as text editor. One of the features I really miss is ability to spell-check multi-language documents. I mean, documents containing text fragments in different languages.

Standard Ubuntu Gedit does not have this capability: I can select only one language at a time from options. Is there a way to configure it to use multiple languages?

Notepad++ uses ASpell for spell checking, which is also available in Linux, as far as I know, but Gedit does not use it directly...

Maybe there is another text editor that will support this feature? I will be happy to use it.